# Can I use raw string literal with variables?

Tags: rust

I know I can use format! to create a String with variables.

```
let name = "rust";
format!("Hi, {}", name);
```

However, I am using a raw string literal to make data in Json format (so that I do not need to use an escape character). Is there any way to use a variable in a string while using a raw string literal?

Comment: You're not really asking anything clear or actionable here. What are you actually trying to achieve? What do you mean by "use a variable [with] a raw string literal"? A raw string is just a way of *parsing* a string, the output is a string all the same, you can use `format!` with that. Though obviously there's a non-insignificant risk that whatever you interpolate will lead to a broken JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To work with owned strings `format!` is a great choice and a good solution. You can use it with syntax below:

```rust
let name = "rust";
format!("Hi {name}");
```

Additionally, as you mentioned using JSON in your project I would like to recommend [serde_json](https://github.com/serde-rs/json) library that provides `json!()` macro which let you write json-like structure that will be serialize/deserialize as you want.

```rust
let name = "rust";
let json = json!(
{
  "foo": name,
  "bar": "kekw"
}
)
```

If do you want more concrete answer, you'll have to provide more information about what you're actually trying to do.